# "WireUpCoreRuntime" tasks fails unexpectedly with a System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am having trouble with a MSBuild 14.0 issue.  I am creating a UWP/x64 Application (we have written the source to be able to run on Windows 8.x, Windows 10 and now Windows 10 Mobile.  My current environment is VS 2015 update 1 running on Windows 8.1.  My code exists on a TFS 2013 local server. I have a build controller and build agent installed from TFS 2015 running on a separate server (server 2012 R2) assigned to my XAML Build Definition.  I can build locally on my server within a Visual Studio 2015 session.  When I Queue a Build. I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets
>   (235): The "WireUpCoreRuntime" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Net.CoreRuntimeTask.WireUpCoreRuntime.CopyWin32Resources(String
>   lpPEFileToReadResourcesFrom, String lpPEFileToInsertResourcesInto)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Net.CoreRuntimeTask.WireUpCoreRuntime.InternalExecute()
>   at Microsoft.Build.Net.CoreRuntimeTask.WireUpCoreRuntime.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Initially I thought this was an environment issue with the build system not on a Windows 10 platform, however, if this was the case I would not be able to build locally in Visual Studio. 
I have Disabled AV on my server for a build with no luck. 
the build Configuration is x64/Release. I have also tried x64/Debug, ARM/Debug and ARM/Release. none of these build configurations work. I think it might have something to do with .NetNative but I cannot be certain.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the file image of a DLL or executable program is invalid, check following things first:

- Make sure that you are not using a component that was created with a
  different version of the .NET Framework.
- Make sure that the file
  image is a valid managed assembly or module.

Detailed information: [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.BadImageFormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx)

Comment: Why would the solution build properly in Visual Studio 2015 but not using MSBuild 14.0?

Comment: @WiSH VisualStudio Description from MSDN: Because Visual Studio runs as a 32-bit application, you could experience problems when your build is processed by a build agent that is running the 64-bit version of Team Foundation Build Service. By specifying X86, you might resolve these kinds of problems. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#build_options